Formula for determining CNC rotary axis travel after rotating part
I am a new member here and work in the CNC machining industry. We have many $5$-axis CNC gantry-type machines. It is a typical CNC with $X, Y$ and $Z$ axes, plus it has $2$ rotary axes $A$ and $B$.  $A$-axis rotates around $X$ and $B$ rotates around $Y$. In case it matters, it is a head/head machine where the $B$-axis caries the $A$ axis.
These machines only have $\pm 20^\circ$ travel on both $A$ and $B$, and many times we have to fight to keep parts within the travel limits. In the past, we have rotated the part around the $Z$-axis, which will gain us a slight amount of travel as long as it is only one of the rotary axis. For example, if the part has a $20^\circ$ chamfer that is parallel to the $X$-axis, it will be within limits. However, if the chamfer is $21^\circ$, the machine cannot reach that far and will overtravel. However, if we can rotate the part around $Z$ to $45^\circ$, then we will be back within travel limits.
Sometimes, the parts are long, so we can only rotate them a few degrees around Z before they stick off the edge of the table. I am trying to figure out a way I can create an Excel formula where we can have one or $2$ inputs like a rotation around $Z $and maybe the feature angle on the part, and it will tell us whether the part will be in travel limits.
Up to now, we have been doing some trial and error with our CNC machine simulator, and it will tell us whether we exceeded limits or not; however, it is time-consuming due to trial and error. I am not very good with this type of math, so I'm looking for some pointers on how to solve this problem via a formula so we can eliminate the trial and error.
Thanks.

@YvesDaoust I believe he is saying that the machine has three axes $X,Y,Z$ with the ability to rotate around the $X$ and $Y$ axes, but sometimes they rotate the material itself (not the machine) about the $Z$ axis.

Obviously this depends highly on the geometry of the part. Is this for predetermined parts, or many different parts you don't control? If the latter case, what sort of measurements are you able/willing to take? What is a "feature angle"? You might be better off asking in a different community, as it seems this might be more of an engineering task rather than a well-constrained mathematical problem.

@NicholasTodoroff, you are correct about rotating the material around the Z-axis.  In regards to your question on feature angle, there are a lot of possibilities due to part characteristics but I think it can be boiled down to the max feature angle on the part.  So if a part has a chamfer on it that is 22 degrees and that was the max feature angle, then that is what we need to try to achieve by rotating the whole part around the Z-axis which will gain us additional rotary travel

So I talked to some other people and they shared this formula which takes advantage of compound angle of both the A and B axis for additional travel.  Compound_Angle=arccos(cos(Angle1)*cos(Angle2)) so if both A and B go +20°, the max angle you can achieve is 27.991°  I assume this would be by rotating the part close to 45 degrees.  Would be nice to create a formulas for what would be the shallowest angle to rotate the part if we only want to achieve 22 degrees?

I still don't understand the setup. I looked up what a "chamfer" is, but I don't know what it means for it to be $22^\circ$. My best guess is that $0^\circ$ is when the chamfer plane is parallel to the vertical edge it is cut out of, and $22^\circ$ would be a slanted cut $22^\circ$ off from vertical?

As for the rotating the machine, what I'm understanding is that if $R_X(\theta)$ and $R_Y(\theta)$ are rotations around the fixed $X,Y$ axes of the "table", then the total rotation is $R(\theta_A, \theta_B) = R_Y(\theta_B)R_X(\theta_A)$ i.e. first rotate around the table $X$-axis, then rotate everything around the table $Y$-axis to get the total rotation. This means that the $B$-rotation is always around the table $Y$-axis but the $A$-rotation is around an axis that changes with $\theta_B$. Is that right?

And then I assume the cutting head starts out being able to make a vertical cut at $R(0,0)$, so that I think what you want to know is what is the largest possible angle-with-the-vertical that the cutting head can achieve with with $-20^\circ\leq\theta_A,\theta_B\leq20^\circ$, and what are directions the cutting head can point in that achieve this maximal angle-with-the-vertical. Is that right?

@NicholasTodoroff You are correct about the chamfer.  They are usually 45 degrees but they can be any degree.  The chamfer I am discussing is 22 degrees from vertical

@NicholasTodoroff You are correct about the rotations.  As I mentioned in my original post, this type of 5-axis machine is a head/head machine.  The B-axis carries A-axis so when B-axis rotates, it changes the plane the A-axis rotates around

Here is a link to a machine similar to ours.  It is actually a 3 spindle machine but it works the same way as a single spindle but it just makes 3 parts at a time.  If you look at the top picture, the X-axis is the main rails on the floor (https://www.fivesgroup.com/high-precision-machines/material-removal/technologies/milling/vertical-milling/profilers)

I probably should have better explained myself about what I meant about rotating the part around the Z-axis.  Lets say the part is 5 foot long by 2 feet wide by 1 foot tall.  The part is usually setup where the longest dimension is running parallel with the X-axis since that is the axis with the most travel.  In this example that would be the 5 foot dimension.  Then we would place the 2 foot dimension in the Y-axis.  If we needed extra rotary travel, we would rotate the part around Z so the 5 foot dimension would no longer be parallel with the x-axis
